# Is $\Box_{n\in\omega} \mathbb{R}$ metacompact?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is $\Box_{n\in\omega} \mathbb{R}$ (that is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ endowed with the [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology)) [metacompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacompact_space)?

Comment: Wikipedia says that the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is paracompact if the continuum hypothesis holds and paracompact spaces are metacompact. So under CH the answer is positive.

Comment: It seems that the paracompactness of the box topology on $\mathbb R^\omega$ can be proved under $\mathfrak b=\mathfrak d$ (which is equivalent to the existence of a scale in $\omega^\omega$).

Comment: @TarasBanakh, Also under $\mathfrak{b}=\aleph_1$ and under $\mathfrak{d}=\mathfrak{c}$.